# Obtaining a reference to the streamManager of the internal object model on twitter.com

Tags: javascript

For a Greasemonkey script running on twitter.com, I need to access the `twttr.streams.TweetStream` instance of the main timeline (dubbed 'Home' internally) programmatically. I'm using Firebug and [Javascript Deminifier](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/javascript-deminifier/) to bring their JS code into a readable form. That way, I could previously work out that I could access it via `twttr.app.currentPage().streamManager.streams.current` in my GM script.

This has worked perfectly over the last months. Today, Twitter seems to have changed their code, breaking my approach (not their fault, obviously ;)).

I can still get to the current page via `twttr.app.currentPage()`. However, it doesn't have a `streamManager` field anymore.

I've tried various paths to get there, but all were dead ends. Unfortunately, I don't completely understand the class system they are using yet. It seems like the `streamManager` property is still there -- on a mixin called `mixins/streamablePage`, which should be provided by the class `twttr.components.pages.Home`. I can't figure out how to access it, though. (Or if the class system hides it in some impenetrable way.) That mixin also provides a `getStreamManager()` method, but I can't access that either, e.g. via `twttr.app.currentPage().getStreamManager()`. Is there any trick I need to perform to get access to these mixins from the outside?

Can anyone spot an alternative method to get to this instance? Note that I need the original instance used on the timeline page. Yes, I could easily create a new instance via `new twttr.streams.TweetStream()`, but I'm trying to hook into the original events.

I am perfectly aware that this use case is as unsupported as it gets, that's why I'm asking you, not them. :) For the record, I'm not attempting to do anything evil, just providing additional functionality for myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until they change it again, twttr.app.currentPage()._instance.getStreamManager()

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much! With that tip, I could get my whole script fixed in five minutes. Would you mind sharing how you got there? What was your approach to figuring this out? (You could edit it into your answer, for example.)